# Z-Index не помогает для кнопок

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Хочу поместить псевдоэлемент на уровень ниже, чем сам элемент `.button__base` или кнопка "связатся с нами", но почему-то не получается.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

.button__base {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #111;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button__base p {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button__base:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  -webkit-animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
  animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
}

.button__base:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

header {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(16.15%, #512DA8), to(#673AB7)), #673AB7;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #512DA8 16.15%, #673AB7 100%), #673AB7;
  height: 60%;
}

header nav {
  background-color: #512DA8;
}

header .options {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 3%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .options .options__item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

header .options .options__item:last-child a {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #03A9F4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

header .options img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="options__item">
        <p>+7 987 654 32 11</p>
        <a class="button__base" href="#">
          <p>связаться с нами</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы анимация(такая) была "под" кнопкой, как вот здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097059/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

.button__base {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

.button__base>span {
  background: #111;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #03A9F4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__base::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  background-size: 400%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  -webkit-animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
  animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
}

.button__base:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

.button__base:hover span {
  background: none;
  border-color: silver;
}

p.tel {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

header {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(16.15%, #512DA8), to(#673AB7)), #673AB7;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #512DA8 16.15%, #673AB7 100%), #673AB7;
  height: 60%;
}

header nav {
  background-color: #512DA8;
}

header .options {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 3%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .options .options__item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

header .options img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="options__item">
        <p class="tel">+7 987 654 32 11</p>
        <a href="#" class="button__base"><span>связаться с нами</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

.button__base {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

.button__base>span {
  background: #111;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #03A9F4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__base::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  background-size: 400%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  -webkit-animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
  animation: button-animation 20s linear infinite;
}

.button__base:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes button-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}

p.tel {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

header {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(16.15%, #512DA8), to(#673AB7)), #673AB7;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #512DA8 16.15%, #673AB7 100%), #673AB7;
  height: 60%;
}

header nav {
  background-color: #512DA8;
}

header .options {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 3%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .options .options__item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

header .options img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="options__item">
        <p class="tel">+7 987 654 32 11</p>
        <a href="#" class="button__base"><span>связаться с нами</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: а можете объяснить, пожалуйста, что вы изменили и от чего вы отталкивались при решении?)